# Getting a Woocommerce product attribute value in a Quform hook

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, attributes, product

I'm trying to get the value of a woocommerce product product attribute (Which name is `dwnfile`).

That value is an url to be passed into hooked function that will populate a form re-direct. The form I'm using is maid with [Quform commercial plugin](https://codecanyon.net/item/quform-wordpress-form-builder/706149).

I have received the code from the authors of the plugin regarding my form settings, but they couldn't advise me on how to get the attribute value.

This is the initial code they gave me:

```
function my_populate_wc_attribute($form)
{
    $value = 'some value'; // Get the value from WooCommerce somehow

    $form->setValue('iphorm_3_2', $value);
}
add_action('iphorm_pre_display_3', 'my_populate_wc_attribute');
```

Here's what I tried:

```
function my_populate_wc_attribute($form)
{
    global $product;
    $value = array_shift( wc_get_product_terms( $product->id, 'pa_dwnfile', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) ) );
    $form->setValue('iphorm_3_2', $value);
}
add_action('iphorm_pre_display_3', 'my_populate_wc_attribute');
```

But the value seems to be empty.

Any help on this please?

Comment: The "`iphorm_pre_display_3`" is not a WooCommerce hook… That means that you are using a third party plugin. You should update your question with more details about this form plugin you are using…

Comment: Thanks.  I modified my question with a few more details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update *(at the end)*:**

Problem remains to **`$product`** global object (that you don't get in this hook).

You should try instead:

```
function my_populate_wc_attribute( $form ) {
    global $post;
    $term = wc_get_product_terms( $post->id, 'pa_nopeus', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) );
    $value = current( $term );
    $form->setValue('iphorm_3_2', $value);
}
add_action('iphorm_pre_display_3', 'my_populate_wc_attribute');
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This should work.

> But this is not the best way to do it. You should add a custom field in the product "General" setting tab, instead of using a product attribute to get an URL value.

---

> **UPDATE:** Your main problem is that **your form is NOT in your product page**, so you can't get the **post ID** `(or the product ID)`.

**You can try to do it with product custom field** (instead of product attributes).

Here is the code for the custom fields:

```
// Add Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_product_options_general_product_data', 'add_product_general_custom_field' );
function add_product_general_custom_field() {
    global $post;

    // Get the selected value
    $value = get_post_meta( $post->ID, '_dwnfile', true );
    if( empty( $value ) ) $value = '';

    woocommerce_wp_text_input( array(
        'id'            => 'dwnfile',
        'label'         => __( 'Download link', 'woocommerce' ),
        'placeholder'   => '',
        'desc_tip'      => 'true',
        'description'   => __( 'Add your download link …', 'woocommerce' ),
        'value'         => $value, // Displaying the selected value
    ) );
}

// Save Fields
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_product_meta', 'save_product_general_custom_field' );
function save_product_general_custom_field( $post_id ){

    if( empty( $_POST['dwnfile'] ) ) return;
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_dwnfile', esc_attr( $_POST['dwnfile'] ) );
}
```

You will get your "Download link" custom field (in the product general options):

[image]

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

> **The form should be on the product page to get the product ID.** if is not the case nothing will work.
>
> So you should better tell what you are trying to do.

To get the url value, you will use:

```
$value = get_post_meta( $post_id, '_dwnfile', true );
```

Or (if product Id is not defined):

```
$value = get_post_meta( get_the_id(), '_dwnfile', true );
```

> Now you can ask authors of the plugin as this is a much more classic way: **post meta data**.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I tried it, but it didn't seem to work.  I changed "pa_nopeus" to "pa_dwnfile" but it didn't seem to flow through.

Comment: @Dan I have updated my answer… The global answer is that **you can't make it work because you never get the post ID**, as your form is not in the product page. So you should better tell what you are trying to do and where is that form located.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  I made one slight change and it seems to work well.  I just changed the code to:    $value = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_dwnfile', true );

Comment: I have updated my answer with get_the_id() … So you are using my custom fields script and it works finally.